# UITableView tracking touches on wrong axis

Tags: ios, cocoa, ipad, uiscrollview, uikit

I have a uitableview controller which is a subview to a view managed by a uiviewcontroller. nothing really out of the ordinary but the tableview tracks gestures on the wrong axis(only on device).

Basically you scroll up/down table doesnt do anything, and left/right scrolls table up/down. its super weird. i was hoping somebody has seen this before and maybe know what causes it?

Edit: heres a video
http://c.drunknbass.com/EB7m

at the end i am scrolling a uiscrollview that scrolls normally and is a child of the same uiviewcontroller.view

Comment: Post code or screenshots.  Are you doing any kind of `CGTransform`s?

Comment: Definitely seen it before, not sure how I fixed it, but it was something trivial. Wild guess: do all your view controllers implement `shouldAutoRotateToInterfaceOrientation:`?

Comment: no transforms and yes the controllers all rotate, the gesture axis  for events on the table are backwards in either orientation.

Answer (score 0):

UIKit relies on there being a key window, and that window having a root view controller, to be able to correctly handle events, and forward them to your code. I suspect that perhaps one of those things is not set up correctly in your app. (Such that the device orientation isn't matching up with the visual orientation of your UI.)

Also note that prior to iOS 5, making one controller's view the child of another controller wasn't really supported by UIKit. It can be done, and mostly works, but you are going to have to manage the forwarding of all of your lifecycle events. (See [the notes on controller containment](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006926-CH3-SW81) in the docs, and the description of [`-automaticallyForwardAppearanceAndRotationMethodsToChildViewControllers`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006926-CH3-SW89) as well.)

Comment: the app has a rootviewcontroller. the vc stack is actually uiwindow->uinavigationcontroller->uiviewcontroller and the view is uiviewcontroller.view->container->uitableview. everything seems ok on the surface.